# Prepared statement for SQL query, error DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703

Tags: java, database, jdbc, db2, sql-insert

I'm currently facing a problem with my SQL query using a prepared statement.

```
String test= "INSERT INTO TEST" + "(ID, IC, CN, CT, Time)" 
             + "VALUES ('"+ ID +"','"+ IC +"','"+CN +"','"+ CT +"','"+ time +"')";  

preparedStatement = myConn.prepareStatement(test);
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

I have successfully connected to the database, and the table is created out. Is it because of the single quotation problem?

Comment: not related : but `PrepareStatement` with concatenation in the query is not logic

Comment: Your question is not complete , add the *datatypes* of the columns in the table, so we can see which values need quoting.

Comment: You need to provide the complete error message. SQLCODE -206 means you reference in your statement a non-existent object (table or column). The error message should contain the name of the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the point of using a `PreparedStatement`. You could just bind the values so you don't have to mess around with quoting yourself:

```
String test= "INSERT INTO TEST (ID, IC, CN, CT, Time) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

preparedStatement = myConn.prepareStatement(test);
preparedStatement.setString(id);
preparedStatement.setString(ic);
preparedStatement.setString(cn);
preparedStatement.setString(ct);
preparedStatement.setDate(new Timestamp(time));

preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```